# Inject all dependencies registered under a token through Injector in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In Angular, we can use

```
constructor(@Inject(SOME_TOKEN) private deps: Foo[]) {}
```

to inject *all* `Foo`s that are provided under `SOME_TOKEN` (using `multi: true`). How can I achieve the same when using the `Injector` API programmatically? The naive

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const deps: Foo[] = this.injector.get(SOME_TOKEN, null);
}
```

won't work since `SOME_TOKEN` is `InjectionToken<Foo>`, and so `get` is typed to return `Foo`, not `Foo[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Its indeed a bit tricky to read the signature of [Injector.get](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get), buts its actually correct.

Take for example the `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` token (working demo in [this blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2pxcqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)):

```
  constructor(private injector: Injector){
    // interceptors´s type is correctly inferred as HttpInterceptor[]
    const interceptors = this.injector.get(HTTP_INTERCEPTORS);
  }
```

In this case, and any others where an `InjectionToken<T>` is used, the inferred type matches the *generic type* of the injection token.

Applied to your case, if you define your token as:

```
const SOME_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Foo[]>("SOME_TOKEN");
```

The following:

```
const deps = this.injector.get(SOME_TOKEN, null);
```

Should correctly infer the type of `deps` as `Foo[]`

Comment: In my case I am actually injecting `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, which is typed as `InjectionToken<ControlValueAccessor>`. So either Injector#get or NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR is typed incorrectly, depending on how Angular intends the API, I guess. I'll update my issue report for sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

It actually appears that `Injector#get` does return an array, as expected, and it's just the typing of the function that is wrong. I've reported this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29351).

A workaround is to explicitly silence the type safety:

```
this.injector.get<any>(…);
```